# Wrapper background not extending to cover height

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a template, we have a background image in the wrapper, but when i'm viewing the website from a laptop 13'' screen, the text extends below the fold, the wrapper only covers above the fold, therefore my content isn't being displayed properly.

How can i fix this? Better yet, how can i make my content fit above the fold.

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/L72wwz7g/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>COMPANYNAME Photo Contest</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/colors/style-color-01.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simple-line-icons.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Start Header -->
    <div id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span12">
            <h1>
              <a href="#">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="COMPANYNAME" />
              </a>
            </h1>
            <h2 class="menulink">
              <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </h2>
            <!-- Start Menu -->
            <div id="menu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#categories">PHOTO CATEGORIES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#tips">PHOTOGRAPHY TIPS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#rules">CONTEST RULES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="current">
                  <a href="https://COMPANYNAME.wufoo.com/forms/COMPANYNAME-photo-contest/" target="_blank">ENTRY FORM</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Menu -->
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Header -->
    <!-- Start Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="inner">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <center>
              <h1 style="color: #464f56">SHOW US YOUR 
              <b>BEST BEFORE AND AFTER</b> PHOTOS AND 
              <b>WIN PRIZES</b> IN THE COMPANYNAME PHOTO CONTEST</h1>
            </center>
            <p>The COMPANYNAME user community is a source of inspiration to us; your remarkable Before &amp; After photos demonstrate the artistry that goes along with the science and technology to create striking results that change lives. To recognize our COMPANYNAME users and encourage you to show off your results, we&#39;re inviting you to enter your best Before &amp; After photos into our photo contest.</p>
            <p>Before &amp; After images are a clear and dramatic way to tell your best patient stories. The COMPANYNAME Photo Contest is a celebration of these patient stories, and an invitation to you to share your results with the COMPANYNAME community.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="inner">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <img src="images/b-a-stacked.png" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <span style="color: #464f56; font-size: 3em;">
              <b>Prizes:</b>
            </span>
            <br />
            <h2 style="color: #ffffff">
              <b>4 First place Prizes!</b>
            </h2>
            <h3 style="color: #ffffff">
              <b>$1,000 + Join the COMPANYNAME Facebook Wall of Fame!</b>
            </h3>
            <h3 style="color: #ffffff">
              <b>In addition, choose:</b>
            </h3>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span style="color: #ffffff;">
                  <b>A night out on the town</b>
                </span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span style="color: #ffffff;">
                  <b>A chair-massage therapy for a day</b>
                </span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span style="color: #ffffff;">
                  <b>$1,000 worth of Top Flight points</b>
                </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <h3 style="color: #ffffff">
              <b>All photos we keep to use are worth $500!</b>
            </h3>
            <p style="font-size:12px">See 
            <a href="#terms">Terms and Condition</a> for full details</p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End content -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="strip features">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <br />
        <a name="categories"></a>
        <h2 style="color: #0658a0">We invite you to submit Before &amp; After photographs in these categories:</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>
          <b>Benign Lesions</b>, such as Angiofibromas, Cutaneous Horn, Milia, Sebaceous Hyperplasia, Skin Tags, Syringoma and Xanthelasma</li>
          <li>
          <b>Benign Pigmented Lesions</b>, such as Benign Nevi, Dermatosis Papulosa Nigra and Keratoses</li>
          <li>
          <b>Other Dermatological Conditions</b>, such as Active Acne, Melasma, Poikiloderma, Rhinophyma, Rosacea, Port Wine Stain, Scars and Warts</li>
          <li>
          <b>Aesthetic Treatments</b>, such as Forever Bare Hair Removal, Forever Young BBL, Pores, Resurfacing, SkinTyte and Vertical Lip Lines</li>
        </ol>
        <br />
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a name="rules"></a>
  <div class="strip highlight strip-alt">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="inner">
            <h2 style="color: #0658a0">Rules:</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Please send before and after photos taken at the same angle, with the same lighting.</li>
              <li>Please include condition treated, modality used, settings, number of treatments, and how long after the treatment the photo was taken</li>
              <li>Photos submitted need to be 
              <a href="http://www.COMPANYNAME.com/sites/default/files/temp/2008-062-01%20Rev%20A%20Patient%20Photo%20Release%20Form.pdf" target="_blank">photo-released</a>. We may use your photo in upcoming campaigns!</li>
            </ul>
            <p>Please feel free to enter as many photos as you&#39;d like. Good luck! We&#39;re looking forward to seeing your photos!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="inner">
            <img src="images/b-a-pic.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="strip highlight">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="inner">
            <center>
              <h2 style="color: #0658a0">The benefits of 
              <span style="color: #000000">Good</span> </br>Clinical
              <span style="color: #000000">Photography</span></h2>
            </center>
            <center>
              <object id="flashObj" width="486" height="412" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">
                <param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
                <param name="flashVars" value="videoId=3721169588001&amp;playerID=96360168001&amp;playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAFkZnkSk~,IiQ79d9fntlYzbIBNabTKGnz_-W-KulR&amp;domain=embed&amp;dynamicStreaming=true" />
                <param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" />
                <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <param name="swLiveConnect" value="true" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
                <embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashvars="videoId=3721169588001&amp;playerID=96360168001&amp;playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAFkZnkSk~,IiQ79d9fntlYzbIBNabTKGnz_-W-KulR&amp;domain=embed&amp;dynamicStreaming=true" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" name="flashObj" width="486" height="412" seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" swliveconnect="true" allowscriptaccess="always" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" />
              </object>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a name="tips"></a>
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="inner">
            <h2 style="color: #0658a0">Photography 
            <span style="color: #000000">tips:</span></h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Make sure you are using a high quality camera with a good lens.</li>
              <li>Mount the camera on a tripod.</li>
              <li>Use the highest resolution possible for your pictures.</li>
              <li>Make sure there are minimal distractions in the background. Shooting on a black background show the best results.</li>
              <li>Isolate the treatment area. When shooting the face, use a headband to hold back hair. Have the patient wear a black drape - light can reflect off of bright colors.</li>
              <li>Put a marker on the wall for patients to look at.</li>
              <li>Always shoot the pictures from the same distance.</li>
              <li>Make sure the lighting is always coming from the same direction.</li>
              <li>Light above the patient will show the most texture - diffuse light with a soft box or with umbrellas.</li>
              <li>Do not set the light up at the same angle as the lens that is shooting the picture.</li>
              <li>Do not use a direct flash.</li>
              <li>Be consistent with the your images. Be aware of :
              <ul>
                <li>Lighting</li>
                <li>Patient position</li>
                <li>Camera</li>
                <li>Camera position</li>
                <li>Patient preparation</li>
                <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
                  <ul>
                    <li>Clothing</li>
                    <li>Jewelry (preferably none)</li>
                    <li>Make-up (preferably none)</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul></li>
              <li>Make sure you are processing the photos in the same way.</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="strip highlight strip-alt">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="inner">
            <a name="terms"></a>
            <h2 style="color: #0658a0">Terms and Conditions:</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>There is no entry fee and no purchase necessary to enter this competition.</li>
              <li>Route to entry for the competition and details of how to enter can be found at www.COMPANYNAME.com/photocontest.</li>
              <li>Closing date for entry will be March 31st, 2015. After this date the no further entries to the competition will be permitted.</li>
              <li>No responsibility can be accepted for entries not received for any reason.</li>
              <li>There will be four winners, one in each category listed above. The rules of the competition and the prize for each winner are as follows: First Place in each category: $1,000, as well as recognition on the COMPANYNAME website and Facebook page, and ONE of the following: A night out on the town for your office staff, hosted by your sales representative OR chair-massage therapist for a day (not to exceed $1,000) OR $1,000 in COMPANYNAME Top Flight Points. We will compensate entrants $500 for any photo we keep and use.</li>
              <li>COMPANYNAME, Inc. reserves the right to cancel or amend the competition and these terms and conditions without notice in the event of a catastrophe, war, civil or military disturbance, act of God or any actual or anticipated breach of any applicable law or regulation or any other event outside of COMPANYNAME&#39;s control. Any changes to the competition will be notified to entrants as soon as possible.</li>
              <li>COMPANYNAME is not responsible for inaccurate prize details supplied to any entrant by any third party connected with this competition.</li>
              <li>No cash alternative to the prizes will be offered.</li>
              <li>Winners will be chosen by a panel of judges appointed by COMPANYNAME.</li>
              <li>The winner will be notified within 28 days of the closing date. If the winner cannot be contacted or do not claim the prize within 14 days of notification, we reserve the right to withdraw the prize from the winner and pick a replacement winner.</li>
              <li>COMPANYNAME will notify the winner when and where the prize can be collected.</li>
              <li>COMPANYNAME&#39;s decision in respect of all matters to do with the competition will be final and no correspondence will be entered into.</li>
              <li>The winner agrees to the use of his/her name and image in any publicity material.</li>
              <li>Entry into the competition will be deemed as acceptance of these terms and conditions.</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem with your markup is your use of `span6` class and the fact that they have `float` styles applied.  Try using `col-sm-6` instead and making appropriate changes for that.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. What do you mean by "the fold"? Btw try getting rid of `height:100%` on `body`. Is that on the right track?

Comment: @Dura: [The fold](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layoutglossary/g/bldeffold.htm) generally refers to the bottom edge of the screen.

Comment: @GVashist Lol, thanks for googling it for me!

Comment: @dura - i'm trying to have the background image cover all the content in the top portion of the page, if you refer to my JSFiddle, you'll see that when you resize the box, push some of the content below the background, making it not possible to read.

Comment: @DennisHo thanks for clarifying. Try change `background-size: cover` to `background-size: contain` on `wrapper` and get rid of `height:100%` on `body`. Is that it?

Comment: @dura - YOU ROCK! That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `background-size: cover` on `wrapper` is your problem.

Change it to`background-size: contain`and get rid of `height:100%` on body.

That will fix your issue.